# JavaScript ／ ページ読込と同時に、クリップボードへ「指定idの文字列」をコピーしたい

Tags: javascript

・zeroclipboardを検討しているのですが、「ボタンクリック」イベントをJSで強制発火することはできないでしょうか？
・通常のボタンとは異なりFlashボタンだから無理？

上記以外で、ページ読込と同時に、クリップボードへ「テキスト」をコピーする方法があれば教えてください

Comment: zeroclipboardを割り当ててあるボタンにたいしてイベント発火できますからできると思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

できません。かならずユーザーによる操作が必要です。

> Adobe AIR のアプリケーションサンドボックスでは、いつでも setData()
>   を呼び出すことができます。他のコンテキストでは、キー入力やマウスクリックなどのユーザー操作に応答する場合にのみ、setData()を呼び出すことができます。

http://help.adobe.com/ja_JP/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#setData()

ユーザーの意志とは関係なしにクリップボードにテキストをコピーする機能には問題があります。例えば、Twitterに文章をコピペしようとしたらいつの間にかクリップボードの中身がスパムメッセージになっている、というような事態が起こりえます。

ですから、もしページ読込と同時にクリップボードにコピーする方法があったとすると、それはセキュリティ上の脆弱性ということになります。